# How do I FTP multiple files from the command line?

Tags: ftp, command-line

I would like to FTP the contents of a directory, but I can't seem to find the right way to use a wildcard. It seems like this would be a common thing to do; is my whole approach wrong?

The command is

```
ftp -s:"C:\Scripts\ftp01" ftpserver.domain.com
```

The script that is called is below. Updated per billinkc.

```
username
password
ascii
cd "/destinationfolder"
lcd "C:\Backup"
mput *.bak
close
quit
```

The script starts, no files are copied and the FTP session remains open.

```
230 User username Logged in Successfully
ftp> ascii
200 TYPE Command OK A
ftp> cd "/destinationfolder"
250 Directory successfully changed to "/destinationfolder"
ftp> lcd "C:\Backup"
Local directory now C:\Backup.
ftp> mput *.bak
mput 9829980.bak? close
mput 6406766.bak? quit
ftp>
ftp>
```

**Conclusion**

I needed to add the flag to suppress the PROMPT command:

```
ftp -i -s:"C:\Scripts\ftp01" ftpserver.domain.com
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Before issuing the `mput` command, issue a [`prompt`](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#prompt) command to disable Interactive Mode.  Once that's off it shouldn't ask you to confirm each file for the `mput` (or  an `mget`).

Comment: For those wondering "what is the syntax of this `prompt` command", you literally just type "prompt" and it toggles prompting from true to false.

Comment: Another way of disabling interactive prompting is to use the `-i` flag on the `ftp` command itself (e.g. `ftp -i -s:"C:\Scripts\ftp01" ftpserver.domain.com`). [The docs](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) describe the `-i` option as: "Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers."

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried using the pathname for local folders, but I have done it by changing the local directory (`lcd`):

```
username
password
ascii
cd "/destinationfolder"
lcd Backup
mput *.bak
close
quit
```

Answer (score 3):

Try inserting the line `prompt n` just before the `mput` line

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mput` command to put multiple files.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am using

Comment: Behind a firewall (particularly SOHO or cheap business grade units)? The built in `ftp` in Windows doesn't support PASV mode, so the transfer will hang and never complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you have administrator rights, you can install [ncftpput](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html). It is easy to use and great for recursive FTP uploads. The switch for recursive transfer is `-R`.

The software is included in most Linux distributions. For Windows it is installable with [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Haegele mentioned, ncftp does this very smoothly on Linux, if you are able and willing to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ncftp
ncftp -R ftpserver.domain.com . /Scripts/ftp01
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the script that I used and that worked for me.

**For ftp1.bat (script):**

```
ftp -i -s:\tmp\ftp.txt
```

**For ftp.txt (script):**

```
Open ip
username
password
prompt
lcd C:\YourFolder\YourFolder
binary
cd /DestinationFolder
prompt
mput *.bak
cd ..
disconnect
quit
```

Maybe there're parts that aren't necessary but I'm putting it as it worked for me, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `mirror` command of `lftp` with `--include` option