# Upload the whole directory with FTP from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, batch-file

I've got this `.bat` file:

```
ftp -s:commands.txt
```

File commands.txt:

```
open www.domain.nl
username
password
cd path/to/upload/to/
prompt
```

How can I now upload the folder where I ran the `.bat` to the server? It doesn't really matter if `upload.bat` and `commands.txt` get uploaded too.

Comment: Note: Depending on how you are using FTP, it might be a good idea to _[find alternatives to FTP](http://blog.jdpfu.com/2011/07/10/why-you-need-to-stop-using-ftp)_ at some point...

Comment: Also see: [How do I FTP multiple files from the command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/358099/how-do-i-ftp-multiple-files-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use `mput *.*` (multiple put).

You *may* need to use `lcd` (local change directory), but not likely. I believe it defaults to the folder the command is run from.

Here is [a list of commands](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) you can use.

Comment: I just tested this, and it works fine for all the files directly in the current directory. However, it gives an error for subdirectories. How can I get this to work?

Comment: unfortunately, with the Windows FTP client, you cant.  You would have to use a 3rd party FTP program such as NcFTP - http://www.ncftp.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the underlying FTP protocol provides for a recursive transfer of a directory. Your best bet is to [zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) it, send it, and then unzip the directory at the remote location.

Comment: could I also automatically zip the folder? and how could I unzip it on the server?